# What are the sentences?

Tags: cipher

Can you figure out what each sentence is?

- 9 1215225 251521.
- 96 9 235185 1 4157, 920 231521124 25 1915 715154.
- 415320151819 1185 141520 15141225 168251993911419.

Comment: Is easiness of a puzzle a good reason to down-vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sentences have simply been encoded using:

> A1Z26, where 1=A, 2=B, etc. based on their positions in the alphabet. The difficulty level has been upped only very slightly by not indicating the separations between letters, which need to be inferred by the reader.

9 1215225 251521.

> 9 12.15.22.5 25.15.21.
>  I L.O.V.E Y.O.U.
>
>  **I LOVE YOU.**

96 9 235185 1 4157, 920 231521124 25 1915 715154.

> 9.6 9 23.5.18.5 1 4.15.7, 9.20 23.15.21.12.4 2.5 19.15 7.15.15.4.
>  I.F I W.E.R.E A D.O.G, I.T W.O.U.L.D B.E S.O G.O.O.D.
>
>  **IF I WERE A DOG, IT WOULD BE SO GOOD.**

415320151819 1185 141520 15141225 168251993911419.

> 4.15.3.20.15.18.19 1.18.5 14.15.20 15.14.12.25 16.8.25.19.9.3.9.1.14.19.
>  D.O.C.T.O.R.S A.R.E N.O.T O.N.L.Y P.H.Y.S.I.C.I.A.N.S.
>
>  **DOCTORS ARE NOT ONLY PHYSICIANS.**